# Merge 2 List of Object by Group of fields

Tags: java, java-8

I have 2 lists of objects that come from 2 tables in database with same set of primary key.

```
public class ObjA {
    private String pk1;
    private String pk2;
    private String pk3;
    private String data1;
    private String data2;
}

public class ObjB {
    private String pk1;
    private String pk2;
    private String pk3;
    private String data1;
}
```

I want to merge field `data1` in `ObjB` into field `data1` in `ObjA` if they have same set of primary key.

I'm using this code but I think it's long code and not efficiency because of complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>)

```
List<ObjA> listA = new ArrayList<>(); //TODO: init
List<ObjB> listB = new ArrayList<>(); //TODO: init

listA.forEach(a -> {
    Predicate<ObjB> objBFilter =
        b -> a.getPk1().equals(b.getPk1())
        && a.getPk2().equals(b.getPk2())
        && a.getPk3().equals(b.getPk3());
    Optional<ObjB> bOpt =
            listB.stream().filter(objBFilter).findFirst();
    if (bOpt.isPresent()) {
        a.setData1(bOpt.get().getData1());
    }
});
```

Is there any way to do this task easily in Java 8?

Comment: Does it have to be done with streams tho? A more optimized solution would be to convert one list into a hashmap with concatenation of pk1+pk2+pk3 as a key and Obj as a value. Then you can get the matching Obj in constant time.

Comment: @Amongalen it doesn’t need to use streams. If we concat 3 primary key to string, I think i will merge wrong object if list contain object like (pk1, pk2, pk3) = (“1”, “23”, “4”) and (“1”, “2”, “34”)

Comment: Extending the original idea by @Amongalen, if you use a separator between keys you can obtain different strings solving  the problem of not unique keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment, this can be done in `O(n)` by creating a hashmap where combination of primary key is a map key and `Obj` or just `data1` is it's value. As you noticed in the comments, there might be some collisions if list contains objects like (pk1, pk2, pk3) = (“1”, “23”, “4”) and (“1”, “2”, “34”). You can easily work around that as well. One way would be to create a separate class to hold the keys in 3 fields. However, if you're sure that those primary keys are always numbers or just that there is some character that won't ever appear in them, you can use that character as a separator.

```
List<ObjA> listA = new ArrayList<>();
List<ObjB> listB = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<>(); //storing concatenation of keys and data1

listB.forEach(b-> mapping.put(b.getPk1()+','+b.getPk2()+','+b.getPk3(), b.getData1())); //using ',' as a separator here.
```

Now that you have the map with additional data, you can access it in a constant time and append to `ObjA`s.

```
listA.forEach(a -> {
    String pkeys = a.getPk1()+','+a.getPk2()+','+a.getPk3();
    String bData1 = mapping.get(pkeys);
    if(bData1 != null){
        a.setData1(bData1);
    }
});
```